# web3py get_logs() can't find my log

Tags: web3.py, logs

I'm trying to retrieve Uniswap logs via `web3py`. Why doesn't my get_logs query match the last log of txn `0xb576ab12c999e20737f478044cd5b0e22c2b324c4125f88404de656f16cd8da4`? Same result for Quicknode and Alchemy providers.

```
w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider(f'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{MYKEY}'))  # also tried: Quicknode
lg = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt('0xb576ab12c999e20737f478044cd5b0e22c2b324c4125f88404de656f16cd8da4')['logs'][-1]
print(lg['blockNumber'])
print(lg['topics'][0].hex())
print(lg['address'])
matching = w3.eth.get_logs({
    'from_block': lg['blockNumber']-1,
    'to_block': lg['blockNumber']+1,
    'topics': [
        '0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67',
    ],
    'address': '0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8'
})
print(matching)  # <-- Prints []?!
```

The output is:

```
15991300
0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67
0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8
[] # <-- Why no matching logs?
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to rename `'from_block' -> 'fromBlock'` and `'to_block' -> 'toBlock'`. I guess they were silently ignored when camelcase.